# Mongoose, populate items that do not match specified value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So let's say I wanted to just populate 'galleries' with the status 'published' I would run:

```
Project.populate(project, [{path: 'galleries', match: {status: 'published'}
```

This works fine. But let's say I want to populate with all galleries *except* those with status 'published'..I tried running the following but it does not work:

```
Project.populate(project, [{path: 'galleries', not: {status: 'published'}...
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question:

```
Project.populate(project, [{path: 'galleries', match: {status: {$ne: 'published'}}}
```